# pandas switch rows with columns and preserve data

Tags: python, pandas

How to replace rows with columns in below data that all data is preserved?

Test data:

```
import pandas as pd

data_dic = {
    "x": ['a','b','a','a','b'],
    "y": [1,2,3,4,5]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)
```

```
   x  y
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  a  3
3  b  4
4  b  5
```

Expected Output:

```
  a b 
0 1 2
1 3 4 
2 NaN 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html):

```
df = df.assign(g = df.groupby('x').cumcount()).pivot('g','x','y')
```

Or [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index([df.groupby('x').cumcount(),'x'])['y'].unstack()
```

---

```
print (df)
x    a    b
g          
0  1.0  2.0
1  3.0  4.0
2  NaN  5.0
```

Comment: there comes another column c in both the solution

Comment: @PrathikKini - Changed OP data in dict for match by output.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you again :)